# Unable to open sql store file used in iOS application

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite, core-data

I am using a sql based database in one of my application with Core Data framework. I have not enabled any file protection for persistent store (using NSFileProtectionKey). But I am unable to open my database file store in a directory under 'Caches' folder in Library.

Have you ever come across such an issue. Below is the image I am getting when I try to open the sql file. However, a difference from iOS 6 I could see in that folder is there are two additional files (-shm and -wal) present with the same name of the sql store file.

[image]

Could anyone please help me to find a solution to open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-shm` and `-wal` are journal files created using write-ahead logging. You need all 3 files for a complete database. I haven't seen an encryption error falsely triggered by not obeying this rule, but it doesn't seem out of the question.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1809/_index.html and http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/207.

Comment: Yes. I have seen this apple technical note. I have not tried the journal delete option. Nevertheless, that wont make a difference I believe since this issue was not visible in iOS 6.

Comment: If the -shm and -wal files exist, then you need to move all 3, and keep them together. Otherwise you have a corrupted database. the .SQL file alone is not sufficient. What happens when you use `sqlite3` from the command line to open the file?

Comment: I tried the options settings and it worked. I am able to open the file as there are no -shm and -wal files. So the way to fix this issue is to enable the SQLPragmaOptions settings with 'journal_mode' to 'DELETE' value.

Thank you @Hal Mueller.